# How can I close all tabs in TabControlEx?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, command

I'm working with the WPF TabControlEx (close tabs).

I'm looking a way to close all the tabs with a ContextMenu in tabs.

I'm using MVVM.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  ...
  <Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="Close tab" Command="{Binding CloseWorkSpaceCommand}" /> <!-- OK -->
      <Separator />
      <MenuItem Header="Close other tabs" Command="{Binding ...Command}" />
      <Separator />
      <MenuItem Header="Close all tabs" Command="{Binding ...Command}" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </Grid.ContextMenu>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: What is TabControlEx ???

Answer (score 0):

If its a normal `TabControl` then i assume you have :

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTabs}"></TabControl>
```

A tab controls with a collection set to the Item source property

Set `MyTabs=new List<Tab>()`  on the `Execute` action for `CloseWorkSpaceCommand`

MyTabs will be a property in ViewModel of your View. ViewModel should Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`